# Maxout neurons: are the weights in the maxout function referring to 2 unique sets of weights?

Tags: machine-learning

I don't understand how maxout works and I suspect it's due to my visualization of the linear algebra multiplication. Basically, I'm under the impression that there are two sets of weights for the maxout functions, both individually trained and then only one is selected. But I'm suspecting this may be wrong, since I don't see a way that two different weights can be trained simultaneously in one feed forward run of the network.

Also, if the two weights w1 and w2 in the function does not refer to two unique sets of weights, then could there be more than two arguments being input to the maxout function, and of which only the max is chosen?

Here is the maxout function I read:

max((w1.T.dot(X) + b1), (w2.T.dot(X) + b2))

Is there a mental representation I could use to visualize this better?

Comment: You can try Danielle Ensign's stellar summary of neural activation functions at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115258/comprehensive-list-of-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-with-pros-cons which includes a long discussion of MaxOut. I was looking for further info and a way to implement it without "sub-neurons" when I ran across your post, so it may not be a complete solution to your dilemma (and mine).

Comment: Also have a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155422/exact-definition-of-maxout?noredirect=1 . After reading Dougal's explanation, I suspect that that I'd find it easier to model using multiple connections between the neurons in two different layers. For example, you could use k number of connections for each pair of neurons, which means you'd calculate k activations for any pair and take the maximum one. If separate biases were required this might not work. I haven't had time to check this solution yet, as I'm trying to solve almost the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I am gonna answer anyway.
[Here](https://youtu.be/ckoD_bE8Bhs?t=1821) you can check out the video by the author of maxout networks Ian Goodfellow, and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64011x02sIkS09hQ0QzZUhXemc/edit) is the URL for the slides used in the video.

Below is the screenshot of the definition of Maxout Networks:

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/962Fe.png)

So it turns out that you are absolutely correct. For each neuron, you create twice weights and twice biases. And if you want more, then you can create n weights and n biases for each neuron and then select with the max value, and do the same with all the neurons in the layer.